# SharePoint - How to show ALL radio button choices on display form?

Tags: sharepoint

I have recently created a sharepoint list that has a multitude of radio button choices. When the user creates a new entry, they pick a radio button and submit. However, when they view using the display form, only the choice that they selected appears. I want to make it so that ALL of the possible choices appear, but it still shows what they have picked. Is there any possible way of doing this?

[This is what appears currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xh8Cx.png)

[This is what I want (and what users see when they submit a new item)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYpXE.png)

Answer (score 0):

We can use REST API to get all the filed choices and then append the HTML to the field in the display form using jQuery. The following code for your reference. Add the code into a script editor web part in the dispform.aspx page.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var fieldTitle="AP Coding/Slip Claim Forms*/Limited Purchase Order";
    var currentFieldValue=$("h3.ms-standardheader:contains('"+fieldTitle+"')").parent().next()[0].innerText.trim();
    var fieldHTML=GetFieldChoices(currentFieldValue,fieldTitle);
    $("h3.ms-standardheader:contains('"+fieldTitle+"')").parent().next().html(fieldHTML);
});
function GetFieldChoices(currentFieldValue,fieldTitle){
    var listId = _spPageContextInfo.pageListId.replace("{","").replace("}","");
    var fieldHTML="";
    var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists(guid'"+listId+"')/fields?$select=Choices&$filter= Title eq '"+fieldTitle+"'";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "GET",
        async:false,
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {       
            var choices = data.d.results[0].Choices.results;
            $.each(choices,function(index,choice){
                if(choice==currentFieldValue){
                    fieldHTML+="<input type='radio' disabled='disabled' checked='checked' name='"+fieldTitle+"' value='"+choice+"'>"+choice;
                }else{
                    fieldHTML+="<input type='radio' disabled='disabled' name='"+fieldTitle+"' value='"+choice+"'>"+choice;
                }
                if(index<choices.length){
                    fieldHTML+="<br>";
                }
            });         
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
    return fieldHTML;
}
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: I just tried on a test list using the same exact fields as you, but for some reason it isn't working. Are there any settings that I need to take into account?

Comment: My test environment is SharePoint 2013 and create a custom list to test it.